# how can write a code that if javascript files do not load reloaded again?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, load

I have a page, php and javascript.  Sometimes, the javascript files do not load, then my page will work properly.

I have include 5 javascript file (jQuery plug-in), i want to know:

1. how can i improve javasccript loader?
2. how can i reload the scriptfile if the script files do not loaded properly?

I have checked when the php page takes more than 10 sec to load the page will be broken.

Thank you

Comment: How you tried to look what is happening with the google chrome dev tool -> network monitor. It bet it is just a timeout.

Comment: yup, the page load is heavy, previously was 5.3MB, later i have decrease it to 3.3 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tip #1:**

Have the Javascript files load at the end of your page.

Javascript does not need to be send over `HTTP` so soon, as it's use is only for dynamic changes after the page is loaded.

Move:

```
    <script  type="text/javascript" src='src/jquery_1.7.min.js' ></script>
    <!-- fancybox -->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-16476667-10']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

        function fireWhenReady() {
            if (typeof function1 != 'undefined') {
                function1();
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(fireWhenReady, 100);
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(fireWhenReady);
    </script>
```

to the bottom of the page.

**Tip #2:**

In addition, try and maintain your Javascript code in two versions:

1. `Sandbox`: Your version of the code which is divided nicely into modules.
2. `Release`: The website's version of the code which is placed all into one Javascript file and minified using something like YUI Compressor. This reduces the file size and increases load speed by decreasing the amount of `HTTP requests` accordingly.

**Tip #3:**

Replace:

`<script  type="text/javascript" src='src/jquery_1.7.min.js' ></script>`

with:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Most users today have the Google API version of jQuery cached so this loads much faster than having to load your version on hand.

Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: Hmm isn't it better to place scripts in the header? semantically speaking

Comment: actually this pages are quite heavy relay on JavaScript, so i can not load it in the bottom since it will break the layout of page at first loading.

Comment: Hi Danial, this is only the case if your page requires Javascript throughout the body. Try your best to place all the Javascript at the end of the page and you will have no problems.

Comment: @Maresh Placing scripts at the end of the document has nothing to do with semantics. This is purely for better performance and consequently better user experience since script will block download of the rest of the document.

Comment: Ok true we can see it that way. But here the whole navigation requires javascript, so he'd avoid loading problem, I guess.

Comment: @HopeIHelped can't agree with #3. The idea is good but in reality doesn't work. Think that each user has very likely different version of jquery. In terms of performance you will be better off to include your version of jquery inside the single "minified" script and save yourself extra http request (slower latency).

Comment: @PeterPajchl, I see what you mean, but it has actually been added as functionality in modern browsers today. Google's inclusion of Ajax libraries was intentional in order to push for JS caching. Even StackOverflow includes jQuery from Google's API (around lines 700-850 in the source).

Comment: ok, Actually i tried to minified and put it in just one javascript file in the header, but my problem become worse. Then, this page http://lib-eguide.nus.edu.sg/books.php?chapterID=4 relay complete on javascript. actually the chapter id is read by javascript the go the same chapter page by javascript. it means if the javascript does not load in the header it would not go to that page of chapter.

Comment: @Maresh.now i load all of the book at the same time, then i faced problem in chapter news since it is RSS, then i just put 4 rss page load by ajax. But this is my last solution, that put every page load by ajax instead of one time. now i do not know how to can solve this problem, i can said before the page size was 5.5MB no i decrease it by ajax and optimizing image to 3.1 MB. the loading page highly improved, also i used gizcompresser on sever side, but i can said 1 out of 20 the page will not load, i have check exactly. when the javascript of page do not load my whole page will be broken.

Comment: @HopeIHelped, agreed, but "each user having different version" does not make sense. The `src` will be parsed by the browser and accordingly be loaded from cache. So it can never be like the browser is loading a different jQuery than what you want, even if loading from from cache

Answer (score 1):

Well the code looks neat.

But I would place the $(document).ready() script in the `<head>` and group css and javascript loading together.

Comment: correct the code is neat , since client change the stricture of code at least three times!!

Comment: Oh, are you loading every pages of the book at the same time??? Could you do it using ajax, it'd greatly decrease loading time !!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments and guessing the problem you might be having, I think your scenario is:

1. You are setting a JavaScript variable in PHP, and using it. All your script is dependent on this variable, and so you need to load that in `head`
2. Things are not executing in order, due to latency.

If above is correct then I think following might work

1. Go ahead with JavaScript in head and have a namespace declared, like **`var MyBook; MyBook.chapterId = <%= echo $chapter-id %>`**. But then move all your other code as last script file before the ending of the body tag.
2. Additionally, load the **`$(document).ready(function() {})`**, and use the `MyBook.chapterId` there. You might use it now for an AJAX call or have a function to load the chapters, and pass this variable to that function